# type mismatch when pulling .value from workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to set up the dashboard I just created to automatically(well, as soon as it gets opened again) update itself as I make changes in the future. I've worked out the following method of doing it, but I keep getting a 'Type Mismatch' error on the line marked with **. I feel like I"m missing something pretty obvious here, but for the life of me, I can't figure it out. Any ideas?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim UpDateBook As Workbook
Dim CurrVer As String
Dim AdminFile As String
Dim AdminFolder As String
Dim MyPath As String

''Change the next two according to where the admin file will be located.
AdminFile = "\\dallfile\Databases\Reports\Dashboard\Dashboard Update.xlsx"
AdminFolder = "\\dallfile\Databases\Reports\Dashboard"

MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
MyPath = MyPath & "\"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set UpDateBook = Workbooks.Open(AdminFile, , True)

**CurrVer = Workbooks(UpDateBook).Sheets("Version_Log").Range("A5000").End(xlUp).Value
CurrVer = CurrVer & ".xlsm"

If ThisWorkbook.Name <> CurrVer Then
    MsgBox ("There is a new update for your file available. It will be loaded as soon as you press OK")
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=AdminFolder & CurrVer
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Workbooks(CurrVer).SaveAs Filename:=MyPath & CurrVer, FileFormat:=xlNormal
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Saved = True
        .ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly
        Kill pathname:=.FullName
        .Close savechanges:=False
    End With
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is because you are using your workbook object incorrectly.

You set the workbook here..

```
Set UpDateBook = Workbooks.Open(AdminFile, , True)
```

and then you should use it like this.

```
CurrVer = UpDateBook.Sheets("Version_Log").Range("A5000").End(xlUp).Value
```

Comment: I literally did a forehead slap right there. Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 2):

Just a matter of syntax.  Once you have:

```
Set UpDateBook = Workbooks.Open(AdminFile, , True)
```

You should use it like:

```
CurrVer = UpDateBook.Sheets("Version_Log").Range("A5000").End(xlUp).Value
```